# How to transform an .txt file to .csv with Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, converters, export-to-excel

**How to transform an .txt file to .csv with Java?**

I did a Java project where I read a .txt file, and I need to use their data to create a .csv file, how should I split the data in the variable where the text is, and how do I turn it into an Excel file (csv)?!

```
public class main {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    File f = main.dialogoDeAbrirArquivo("Abrir...", 
            JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY, false, new FileNameExtensionFilter("Text File", "txt"),null, null);
}

public static File dialogoDeAbrirArquivo(String tituloDaJanela, int selectionMode, boolean acceptAllFileFilterUsed,
        FileNameExtensionFilter filtro, Component componente,File defaltDirectory) {

    UIManager.put("FileChooser.openDialogTitleText", tituloDaJanela);
    final JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(selectionMode);
    fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(acceptAllFileFilterUsed);
    fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(defaltDirectory);

    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x = (dim.width - fileChooser.getSize().width) / 2;
    int y = (dim.height - fileChooser.getSize().height) / 2;
    fileChooser.setLocation(x, y);

    fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filtro);

    int retorno = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(componente);
    if (retorno == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File arquivo = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        System.out.println("Open file: " + arquivo.getName());
        return arquivo;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Show us a sample of the input and how you want the output to look like.

Comment: its something like this http://bit.ly/1vefq0R;

Comment: and i just need to split, but that's its not the problem, if i could make just a simple table like "123 - Name, 234 - name2 " it would be great!

Comment: It is difficult to tell how this input is structured. Do the columns have fixed width? Are tabs or spaces used? That is important for us to answer your question.

Comment: think as if it were only two strings separated by a single space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must consider the **content** you want to transform; usually, with a simple text, you can arrange a renaming of the file in .csv

otherwise is preferable to use some libraries to create an excel spreadsheet as [Apache POI HSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/) provides to

with **HSSF** you can directly work on workbooks, sheets and cells managing your content

in your case, for the simple renaming:

```
File fo = new File(arquivo+".csv");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(<some path>+"\\"+fo);
PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(fos);   

write.println(text);
write.close();
```

Comment: nice, i'll study this HSSF, and i think that will be very helpful!